# What was going on with the person in the glass box?

Tags: ares

In the show *Ares*, we see an elderly person in a glass box who appears to be the one who *really* gives the orders in the titular organization. Said individual is present in a flashback in which someone gives their "soul" to "Beal," and appears to live in a completely sealed glass box. Also, they chant some sort of spell, or something, when Rosa is standing before the Beal pool. However, unless I missed it, their relation to the organization is otherwise unclear.

Who are this person? Why are they in a glass box?